# Conditional Cumulative Average in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple table, which is:

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS running_averages;

    CREATE TABLE running_averages
    (
            avg_id          SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
            num1             integer,
            num2             integer   DEFAULT 0     

    );

    INSERT INTO running_averages(num1, num2)
    SELECT 100, 100 UNION ALL
    SELECT 200, 175 UNION ALL
    SELECT -400, NULL UNION ALL
    SELECT 300, 200 UNION ALL
    SELECT -100, NULL;
```

In the above table the "num2" column should be updated with the cumulative average of **the previous row** if the column "num1" is a negative value. My current query is :

```
    SELECT *,
            num1 * num2 AS current_total,
            SUM(num1 * num2) OVER(order by avg_id) AS cumulative_sum,
            SUM(num1)  OVER(order by avg_id) AS culmulative_num1,

            CASE WHEN num1 > 0 THEN
            SUM(num1 * num2) OVER(order by avg_id) 
            / 
            SUM(num1)  OVER(order by avg_id) 
            ELSE
            0
            END AS cumulative_average
    FROM running_averages;
```

The result:

```
avg_id  num1  num2    current_total cumulative_sum   cumulative_num1 cumulative_average
1       100   100     10,000        10,000           100             100
2       200   175     35,000        45,000           300             150
3       -400          NULL          45,00            -100            0
4       300   200     60,000        105,000          200             525
5       -100          NULL          105,000          100               0
```

I cannot figure out the way to **bring the cumulative average of the previous row** if the current row's num1 column is a negative number. Instead of the above, the expected output should be :

```
avg_id  num1  num2    current_total cumulative_sum   cumulative_num1 cumulative_average
1       100   100     10,000        10,000           100             100
2       200   175     35,000        45,000           300             150
3       -400  150     -60,000       -15,00           -100            150
4       300   200     60,000        45,000           200             225
5       -100  225     -22,500       22,500           100             225
```

How can I get the value of the last row's column in this case?

### Edit:

I edited the SQL Script above. I quite like the approach of [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff)'s answer. But it sadly produces incorrect result as per the script change:

```
avg_id  num1  num2    new_num2
1       100   100     100
2       200   175     175
3       -400  150     150 (Correct)
4       300   200     200
5       -100  225     50  (Incorrect)
```

### Edit 2

I also tested answer of [Multisync](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4108552/multisync), it also produces wrong result:

```
avg_id  num1  num2              current_total cumulative_sum   cumulative_num1 cumulative_average
1       100   100               10,000        10,000           100             100
2       200   175               35,000        45,000           300             150
3       -400  150 (Correct)     -60,000       -15,00           -100            150
4       300   200               60,000        45,000           200             225
5       -100  175 (Incorrect)   -17,500       27,500           100             275
```

### Edit 3

I have accepted the updated answer of Multisync, since it produces correct results. I would also like to know on how I can improve queries like this where we have a lot of aggregate and window functions. Any reference on this topic will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of only a recursive query:

```
with recursive tmp (avg_id, num1, num2, sum_m, sum_num1, last_id) as (
  select avg_id, num1, num2, num1 * num2, num1, avg_id
  from running_averages where avg_id = 1  
  union all
  select r.avg_id, r.num1, 
         case when r.num1 < 0 then t.sum_m / t.sum_num1 else r.num2 end, 
         t.sum_m + case when r.num1 < 0 then t.sum_m / t.sum_num1 else r.num2 end * r.num1,
         t.sum_num1 + r.num1,
         r.avg_id 
  from running_averages r join tmp t on r.avg_id = t.last_id + 1
)
select avg_id, num1, num2, 
       num1 * num2 AS current_total,
       SUM(num1 * num2) OVER(order by avg_id) AS cumulative_sum,
       SUM(num1) OVER(order by avg_id) AS culmulative_num1,
       SUM(num1 * num2) OVER(order by avg_id) 
       / SUM(num1) OVER(order by avg_id) AS cumulative_average
from tmp;
```

`avg_id` must contain consequtive numbers (you can use `row_number()` instead, I didn't use it for simplification)

`num2` is changing during the calculation that's why I can't think of anything other then recursive queries (output of the previous step is the input of the next step)

Comment: This is also producing wrong results after I tested it in my real table. I have edited the question on why it is showing wrong results.

Comment: @Nancy It produced the result from your question a day ago )

Comment: My apologies. While trying to simplify the database script, I missed it. (

Comment: @Nancy Sorry, I've checked my answer - there was a mistake. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Actually I came up with a solution myself. But this one is a thousand times better than mine. :P

Answer (score 2):

Let's focus on this:

> In the above table the "num2" column should be updated with the
>   cumulative average of the previous row if the column "num1" is a
>   negative value

That should not be too difficult:

```
select ra.*,
       (case when num1 >= 0 then num2
             else avg(num1) over (order by avg_id rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
        end) as new_num2
from running_averages ra;
```

I think you can do the rest of the calculation using `new_num2`.

Comment: I have edited the question since it produced a wrong result when a new negative row is introduced. Could you please have a look on this? :)